# Delete records using TFDQuery in Delphi

Tags: sql-server, delphi, pascal, using, delete-record

Help me to fix this problem to delete records with `TFDQuery`.

When this value of record is choosed by me with `Edit.Text` or `DBEdit.Text`, I try like this but it is not working:

```
FDQuery.SQL.Text := 'delete * FROM MyTable column_name =:KEY1 ';
FDQuery.ParamByName('KEY1').AsString = 'dbedit.text';
FDQuery.Open;
```

Comment: (1) `delete from`, not `delete * from`. (2) `DBEdit.Text`, not `'DBEdit.Text'`. (3). Execute the query; don't open it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```pascal
  fdquery.SQL.Text := 'DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE column_name = :KEY1';
  fdquery.ParamByName('KEY1').AsString := dbedit.Text;
  fdquery.Execute();
```

You could also use TFDCommand rather than TFDQuery as you are not expecting to read the result:

```pascal
  fdcommand.CommandText := 'DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE column_name = :KEY1';
  fdcommand.ParamByName('KEY1').AsString := dbedit.Text;
  fdcommand.Execute();
```

If this is a command you expect to re-use you could put the SQL statement into the command at design time, with the parameter name, and then at run time you would only need to do:

```pascal
  fdcommand.ParamByName('KEY1').AsString := dbedit.Text;
  fdcommand.Execute();
```

Depending on the underlying database you are using have commands pre-populated can allow the query to be prepared in advance.  For complex queries (unlike this one) this means that the execution plan is built only once.